# How to add double x-axis label on highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Now I have following highchart with only one label on x-axis:

[image]

And I wish to have double label which is as below:

[image]

Anyone have any idea?

This is my x-axis data:

[image]

And I keep the ww in form of array and I pass{{array|safe}} to the highchart javascrip, for now I need to add on the month

Comment: [black label](https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin is what you required

Comment: thanks, but any idea on how to make it dynamic?, because 201611 is for 201648, while 201612 is for 201649... that mean while the top label was change, the lower part label will change automatically

Comment: can you update your post with the data. you are using

Comment: above pic is my data and I have multiple x axis but without multiple series

Comment: adding pic will not solve, I want data which you are bringing from server side  to create chart